# How join in linq to nhibernate

Tags: linq, join, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a linq query in Nhibernate.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.FirstName))
   q = q.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(dto.FirstName));
```

This query is for Search in persons list. I need to add a join between Person and Employee classes. for add a `where` condition on a property in Employee class.

For example it :

```
if (dto.Type == PersonEnumType.EmployeeType)
   q = q.Where(employee => employee.Code.Contains(dto.Code));
```

How can I add something like it?

**My sql query is similar this :**

`select * from Person_Table 
left outer join Employee_Table on Person_Table.Id = Employee_Table.Person_id_fk
where Person_Table.FirstName like '%Phill%' and Employee_Table.Code like '332'`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how to do this without knowing your mappings, but it could be something like this:

```
q.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(dto.FirstName))
    .Where(x => x.Employees.Any(emp => emp.Code.Contains(dto.Code)))
```

If there is a Person.Employees at all. But I must admit I don't know if Linq to NHibernate supports `Any()`. That probably depends on which vesion of L2N you use.

If this does not work you should try your luck with `GroupJoin()` (because of the outer join), but I'm even more insecure about solid L2N support for that one. As far as I can see it is in L2N since 3.0 beta, but whether it is reliable...?